# Modify DateTime Object In LWC (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, datetime

**tl;dr** - How do I access and modify the properties of a DateTime object in LWC?

I'm trying to create code that will populate an HTML field with the current date-time, adn the current date-time plus 30 minutes. My current code is as follows:

**Javascript**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getNowPlusThirty from '@salesforce/apex/MeetingMakerUtil.getNowPlusThirty';

export default class findingNow extends LightningElement {

    now = Date.now();

    @wire(getNowPlusThirty)
    endDateTime;

}
```

**Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Datetime getNowPlusThirty(){
    return system.now().addMinutes(30);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <p>Datetime: --|{now}|--</p>
  <p>EndTime: --|{endDateTime}|--</p>
</template>
```

The results render as follows:

- Datetime results in something like this: `Now: 1583535981831`
- EndTime results in this: `EndTime: --|object Object|--`

I need to know how to modify the serial code `1583535981831` to get things like year and time formatting, and the dateTime object `object Object` in the same way. My attempts at using normal javascript formatting such as `Date.now().format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a')` have simply thrown errors.

Comment: You could just do it all in js: var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 30);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LWC doesn't track the internals of properties of certain objects, like Date.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.reactivity_data_types

You'll need to output the value as a string and assign it to a property.

As for the the other issue, try replacing:

`<p>EndTime: --|{endDateTime}|--</p>`
with 
`<p>EndTime: --|{endDateTime.data}|--</p>`

Comment: Thanks Ben. `endDateTime.data` did the trick

Answer (score 5):

You can use lightning-formatted-date-time, as in:

```
<lightning-formatted-date-time value={now}></lightning-formatted-date-time>
```

Or you can use a getter to format this:

```
get nowFormatted {
    return now.toLocaleString(); 
}
```

To get thirty minutes from now, you can just add it to the existing value:

```
get nowPlusThirtyFormatted() {
    let nowPlusThirty = new Date();
    nowPlusThirty.setMinutes(nowPlusThirty.getMinutes()+30);
    nowPlusThirty = new Date(nowPlusThirty);
    return nowPlusThirty;
}
```

For your wire property, remember that it returns an object with two properties. In your example, `{endDateTime.data}` contains the actual DateTime value.

---

Side note: Don't use a @wire like this, since it won't be updated until the cache expires for that Apex call, which will cause issues. cacheable=true is meant to be used for idempotent calls (i.e. the same method called with the same parameters should produce the same output each time). You'll be off by a few minutes until/unless the cache decides to expire.